# Replace Docker container with external service

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm just getting started with Docker, and I read a ton of documentation and tutorials yesterday, but I can't find where I read about replacing an external service using a linked container, and I'm not even sure which terminology to search for.

Say there is an `apache` container and a `mysql` container, where `apache` was run with a link to `mysql`, and has access to its ports and such. Now instead of MySQL running on the container instance, we move it to AWS RDS, for example. How do you modify the `mysql` container so that `apache` continues to run as expected? To clarify, `apache` would still be run with a link to a container with the alias `mysql`, but the `mysql` container would take care of getting traffic on that port sent to AWS.

Alternatively, maybe there is a container running a MySQL service, but that container is on another host. I have a vague feeling that the pattern I'm referring to would be able to handle that scenario as well. Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.docker.com/articles/ambassador_pattern_linking/ ?

Comment: ambassador pattern, yes, this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

If the container is on another host, why not just hit the host directly and have docker be transparent with 3386 (or whatever port you're running mysql on) forwarding requests to the container? I can't think of any reason you'd want to link containers unless they're actually on the same host. Docker is great at being transparent, so clients can run things against a service in Docker from another machine as if the service was being run directly on the machine without Docker.

If you really have to have both containers on the same machine (even though the mysql container is calling out to RDS or another host), you should be able to make a new simple mysql image that just has mysql_client installed and just takes requests and forwards them to RDS.